# Posting testimonials to Facebook business page from website cms

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, content-management-system

Sorry if this has been dealt with before, but my website guy is having issues getting this to work.
I am using facebook open graph api to post a testimonial from my PHP website CMS to my facebook business page. 
I have a facebook profile and created a business page from my profile.
I have also created an app under my profile to get an app id and secret key which is used for the graph api to post on behalf of me from my website to my facebook businness page. The issue is I need the post to go directly to my business page and be posting as my business, not as or on behalf of me. Currently the api is sending the posts directly to my profile wall showing as me sharing a link via my business page and it doesn't appear on the business page at all.  I need a way to post the testimonial to my business page directly rather than on my profile wall. How do I do that?  My understanding is he has used the personal ID & App secret and also the business page app ID & secret, but seem to get the same result.
The code below is what is being used, any assistance would be greatly appreciated;

```
<?php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'myappid',
    'secret' => 'mysecrectkey',
));
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {   
    try
    {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $AccessToken  = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $data = array("message" => $pdes,"link" => "http://www.website.com.au/testimonial.php", "name" => $name);
        $share = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "POST", $data);
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is your personal Facebook account also admin for the Page in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is here:

```
$share = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "POST", $data);
```

This code sends message to your wall, instead of the page. In order to post on your Facebook page on behalf of your page, first, your app needs to get `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions. Once you have it you need to do is get the access token of the page you want to post on:

```
$pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
foreach($pages as $page)
{
 if($page['id'] == YOUR_PAGE_ID)
    $data['access_token'] = $page['access_token'];
}
```

Once you have page access token you must use it to send message on your page's wall:

```
$facebook->api(YOUR_PAGE_ID . '/feed', 'POST', $data);
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated, I have passed to my web guy and awaiting his response.

Comment: Hi Darvex,
Thought I would include this question.  The testimonials include text and sometimes 1 to 2 pictures, is there anything specific to make sure all will post to Facebook business page.  Thank you again.

Comment: I don't believe that there's anything specific that has to be done for that, as long as sharing several pictures is possible (never tried it, can't really say). You can read about page posts [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts)